# Matrix sum implies equality

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a sequence of matrices, $A_1,...A_k$, each of dimension $n \times m$. Suppose I also have two $m \times m$ matrices $B$ and $C$. What are the broadest conditions under which its true that:

$$\sum_i A_i B A_i' = \sum_i A_i C A_i'$$

Implies $B=C$? And when does this implication definitely not hold?

Comment: Is the equation supposed to hold for all $j$?  Or is the sum supposed to be indexed over $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Ah damn sorry this is a typo it should be $i$ in both.

Comment: See my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator, we find that the matrix of the linear map $X \mapsto \sum_{i} A_i X A_j'$ is given by
$$
M = \sum_i \bar A_i \otimes A_i,
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. It will hold that $\sum_i A_i B A_i' = \sum_i A_i C A_i'$ implies that $B = C$ if and only if the matrix $M$ is invertible.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to follow up so much later on, but I have just realised; what happens here if M is not square?

Comment: @JDoe2 The same formula works in that case

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that it only holds for M invertible in the case M is square though? Would the equivalent condition be M must have a right pseudoinverse for the case M is not square?

Comment: I see. If $M$ is not square, then $x \mapsto Mx$ is invertible iff the columns of $M$ are linearly independent.  This in turn is equivalent to the condition that $M'M$ is invertible. I'm not sure what you mean by "right pseudoinverse", but $M$ has a left-inverse (and not necessarily a right one) since $[(M'M)^{-1}M']M = I$.